# How to get profile data in complex case using passport-facebook in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm using `passport-facebook`, but this way -

```
app.get('/oauth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {}));
```

doesn't fit my requirements, cause I need to save data in the session. It won't work if I just put `passport.authenticate` in another function, like this:

```
app.get('/oauth/facebook', function (req, res, next) { 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {});
}); // doesn't work
```

But it works if I call this function, like this:

```
const fbAuth = (req, res) => {
    req.session.isRegisterUser = req.query.isRegisterUser || false;
    req.session.regUserId = req.params.id > 0 ? req.params.id : null;
    req.session.redirectUrlAfterSignIn = req.query.redirectUrl ? req.query.redirectUrl : null;

    return passportFacebook.authenticate('facebook', {}, function() {
        // NEVER called
        console.log('auth cb');
    });
};

// this is the only way I could pass (req, res)
router.get('/oauth/:id/facebook', 
    (req, res) => fbAuth(req, res)(req, res));
```

It doesn't call third parameter function, but it redirects. So after this, it goes to the callback function:

```
const fbCb = (req, res) => {
    return console.log(req.session.regUserId);
};

router.get('/oauth/facebook/callback', (req, res) => fbCb(req, res)(req, res));
```

And this works, but how can I get profile data? Cause in my URL there is only parameter `code`, which is access_token if I understand correctly.

I initialise Strategy the same way as in documentation:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const Strategy = require('@passport-next/passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new Strategy({
        clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3001/api/oauth/facebook/callback',
        graphApiVersion: 'v3.1',
        // scope: ['email']
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        // NEVER called
        console.log(`accessToken`, accessToken);
        console.log(`profile`, profile);
        return cb(null, profile);
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    return models.User.findById(id).then(user=>{
        done(null, user);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        done(null, null);
    });
});

module.exports = passport;
```

But `function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb)` never called. However, I need an access to request, that I can check my session data, so I need all this in my callback function, not here.

So, I'm a bit frustrated, why it become so complex. To solve this, probably I can get data by URL `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me?...` and parse JSON. But why I need this library then?!

You can find all code [here](https://gist.github.com/zishe/b0a5e72c44b56b35c60048c4bc93df87)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's necessary to call `passportFacebook.authenticate` second time to call callback. And it's possible to do this inside function, the only thing that you should return the result of a function `passportFacebook.authenticate` (call it). [Final code](https://gist.github.com/zishe/69e0a9a89eeeb8b2cafb0c668d6fa2e4)